# What is .linear_model in sklearn.linear_model

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I want to know what is the meaning of **.linear_model** in the following code -

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
```

My understanding is **sklearn** is the **library/module** (both have same meaning) and **LogisticRegression** is the **class** inside this module.

But I'm not able to understand what `.linear_model` means?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`linear_model` is a module.  `sklearn` is a package.  A package is basically a module that contains other modules.

Comment: Thank you Bren. One more question - does library and package carry same meaning?

Comment: I would say "library" is a somewhat more generic term.  A library could be a collection of modules and/or packages.

Answer (score 0):

`linear_model` is a class of the `sklearn` module if contain different functions for performing machine learning with linear models.

The term linear model implies that the model is specified as a linear combination of features. Based on training data, the learning process computes one weight for each feature to form a model that can predict or estimate the target value.

It includes :

> Linear regression and classification, Ridge regression and classification, Lasso, Multi-task Lasso
> etc..

Check the [sklearn doc](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html) for further details.